# Why did the WannaCry ransomware kill switch check whether it was within a virtual environment in this manner?

Tags: ransomware, wannacry

I have been researching the Wannacry ransomware, and have seen an example of the kill switch within Ghidra. What baffles me is, why did they implement the kill switch as a web domain instead of any other alternative methods, or why implement a kill switch in the first place.

From what I have read, the kill switch was either a way to check that it was running within a virtual environment, or to prevent the ransomware from spreading too much. The latter does not seem likely, as they would want to benefit from this ransomware as much as possible.

By registering the domain, it essentially rendered all strains of the malware checking against that domain useless, which seems to be a huge oversight from the malware developers.

Wouldn't there be better alternatives to check for a virtual environment instead of checking against a single web domain?

Comment: A possible explanation for the reason is done by the one detecting the kill-switch: https://www.malwaretech.com/2017/05/how-to-accidentally-stop-a-global-cyber-attacks.html. It also states that this way is not unusual and also used by other malware. Could one do better -  probably. But that's a statement one can very often do afterwards - see [hindsight bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindsight_bias)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply and help!